# Refactoring legacy code with Java8 Optional<T>

Tags: java, lambda, refactoring, java-8, option-type

Consider I have a simple models UserInfo and Passport:

```
public class UserInfo {
    private int age;
    private String passportId;
    // getters, setters
}

public class Passport {
    // empty
}
```

If user is older then 20 years I want to see his passport, in Java7 I do:

```
    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
    userInfo.setAge(22);
    userInfo.setPassportId(null);

    final Passport passport;
    if (userInfo.getAge() > 20) {
        if (userInfo.getPassportId() == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Set passport");
        }
        else {
            passport = findPassportById(userInfo.getPassportId());
        }
    }
```

It is pretty straightforward but I want to use a Java8 **Optional< T >**.

Optional seems very handy if you need to do only one action with nullable:

1. throw an exception if null using **.orElseThrow()**
2. do some computation in case of value exists (in my case *findPassportById*) using **.ifPresent()**

But when I try to do both I am getting something ugly:

```
    String passportId = Optional.of(userInfo)
            .filter(x -> x.getAge() > 20)
            .map(UserInfo::getPassportId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Set passport"));

    final Passport passport;
    // null checks again? I don't want to!
    if (passportId != null) {
        passport = findPassportById(passportId);
    }
```

So there is any practice to refactor this common case in more clean way?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually you don't need to do that `null` check, as for null value, the first statement will itself throw exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `UserInfo` won't be `null`, so wrapping it into an `Optional` doesn't make sense. You also don't want to continue when the age is below 20.

Something else to keep in mind is that the main point of `Optional` is to **avoid** exceptions. If `passportId` is an essential property then it should be mandatory (if the age is > 20) anyway. Otherwise you would be working with corrupt data in the first place. If on the other hand it isn't mandatory, then throwing an exception doesn't make much sense.

If you don't want to make it mandatory I suggest to make an `Optional` of `passportId`, maybe directly by `UserInfo` itself. If you still need your conventional getter then you can add a new method using the property's name (that seems to be common practice, even within the JDK).

```
public class UserInfo {

  public String getPassportId() {...}

  public Optional<String> passportId() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(passportid);
  }

  ...

if (userInfo.getAge() > 20) {
  userInfo.passportId().ifPresent(...)
}
```

If you insist, however, on throwing an exception you can go that way:

```
if (userInfo.getAge() > 20) {
  Passport passport = userInfo.passportId()
                       .map(this::findPassport)
                       .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Set passport"));
  ...                            
}
```

Comment: Note that this would throw the same exception if the password id is set (not null) but is not valid (passport doesn't exist).

Comment: @СӏаџԁеМаятіи Well, having a non-existing passport is essentially the same as having no passport ;) I don't assume that a wrong id would be set, but you are right, "Set passport" would be misleading.

Answer (score 2):

Your main misconception is the fact that you check the age *ouside* your class `UserInfo`. In fact, your user information class is simply a record or a struct.

This clearly violates the OOP paradigm (i.e. this is procedural style). What, if you need this age checking in other places, too? Do you really want to copy the this code snippet to all those places? What, if the age limit changes to another value (say 18, for example, as it is in Germany)?

Conclusion: The age checking behavior should be in a single place, only. This is called the *Single Responsibility Principle* (SRP). Here, this feature clearly belongs to the class `UserInfo`.

So you could change it to:

```
public class UserInfo {
    private int age;
    private String passportId;

    ...

    public Optional<String> getPassportId() {
        checkPassport();
        return Optional.ofNullable(passportId);
    }

    private void checkPassport() {
        if (age > 20 && (passportId == null || passportId.isEmpty())) {
            throw ...
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the getter now will either result in an exception or in an optional that maybe encapsulates the passport id. Whether throwing an exception is the correct handling, is another issue.

Note, that I did not elaborate much on this issue. For example, the age checking itself should again be outsourced into a [*strategy* object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Additionally, I highly recommend to make the class [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). In doing so, you should consider checking the arguments while the object is being constructed. But this depends on your application requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If `getPassportId` returns null, `orElseThrow` will trigger the exception.  In your code `passportId` will never be `null`.  You can combine it all together like this:

```
Passport passport = Optional.of(userInfo)
  .filter(x -> x.getAge() > 20)
  .map(UserInfo::getPassportId)
  .map(this::findPassportById)  // or wherever findPassportById is defined
  .orElsethrow(...);
```

Comment: If age is below 20 then _.orElsethrow(...)_ will be thrown, won't it?
I don't need to make a check for passport if age < 20.
The only solution comes in mind to move this condition to the If above:

`if (userInfo.getAge() > 20) {
   // other logic
}`